# Linux shell scripting: Is it possible to modify the variable sent as parameter to a function?

Tags: bash, function, variables, parameters

I am a bit new to linux shell scripting, so this could be a very silly question.

This is a simple example code (of course it does not work, but I am hoping to show what I wanna do):

```
#!/bin/bash 
function AppendLetters() {
  # Value sent as parameter: $1
  $1= "$1"LLL
}
var="foo"
AppendLetter $var
echo "$var"
```

So, when calling the program from command line:

```
$ ./example.sh
```

I would like to modify the internal variableobtain some sort of:

```
fooLLL
```

**Reason** for doing this: I have a script that loads **multiple variables** from a config file, and would like to make **the same modification** to that variables in order to use them in my program.

Is it possible? Can a function modify variables sent as parameter?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 covers all sorts of details about this sort of indirect assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Bash 4.3.0 you can use `declare -n` to get **reference** of a variable in a function:

```
AppendLetters() {
   declare -ln ref="$1"
   ref+="LLL"
}

var="foo"
AppendLetters "var"

echo "$var"
fooLLL
```

From `help declare`:

```
-n  make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value
```

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to @gniourf_gniourf for suggesting this `printf`, you can do this in older BASH:

```
AppendLetters() { printf -v "$1" '%sLLL' "${!1}"; }

var="foo"
AppendLetters "var"

echo "$var"
fooLLL
```

Comment: Rulez! But is there any special reason for your `{` instead of my `"` in the appending `LLL` line?

Comment: You could do `ref="$ref"LLL` also but this gives you flexibility to add a value with space also like: `ref="${ref}LLL MM NN"`

Comment: With Bash<4.3, you'd do: `declare "$1"+=LLL`. If you want to use `declare -n` (which is not really justified for this anyway, unless you want to explicitly check that you have a valid identifier—yet you could use `printf` for that), it's still better to use `ref+=LLL`. Also, declare your `ref` variable local as `declare -ln ref="$1"`. Another option is to use `printf` with the `-v` switch.

Comment: Thanks @gniourf_gniourf: I updated this example but sorry didn't get how to use `printf -v` to modify variable outside.

Comment: You can use `printf` as: `printf -v "$1" '%sLLL' "${!1}"`.

Comment: It's safer to use the command I gave: `printf -v "$1" '%sLLL' "${!1}"` in case the expansion of `${!1}` yields percents or backslashes.

Comment: Always the sane advise @gniourf_gniourf, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Without needing bash 4.3, using [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
AppendLetters() {
  declare -g "$1"="${!1}LLL"
}

var=f00
AppendLetters var
echo "$var"
```

```
f00LLL
```

The `-g` option for declare is necessary so that the assignment is not treated as local to the function.

---

Given:

> I have a script that loads multiple variables from a config file, and would like to make the same modification to that variables in order to use them in my program.

I would do this, not in a function, using bash's `+=` assignment operator

```
varlist=( var1 var2 var3 )
for varname in "${varlist}"; do
    declare "$varname"+="LLL"
done
```

Comment: Same comment as in anubhava's post: you could definitely use `declare -g "$1+=LLL"` (this completely avoids indirection). Or use `printf`.

Comment: Excuse me, @glennjackman, could you please tell me what does the `!` symbol means in the `${!1}LLL` part?

Comment: Follow the "variable indirection" link at the top of my answer.